# TV with broken audio jack how to connect wireless headphones?

Tags: audio, headphones, television

I have a television with an audio jack, which I used in order to connect to my wireless headphones (through a connecting base sold with the headphones).

Unfortunately, the audio jack is now damaged, and I would like to understand how I can use wireless headphones without it.

The television does not have Bluetooth connectivity, but it has RCA and optical cable connections available.

I would prefer a solution where the audio goes through the RCA/optical cable permanently, without having to plug in the cables every time I need to use the headphones to the television.

Perhaps a soundbar or a surround sound system, which is then able to connect to a wireless headphone, even if it implies buying both.

I would like to spend not more than 150$, if possible.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Does the headphone base have any other connectors? What about a 3.5mm (or whatever the size of the jack) to RCA adapter?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Thanks, I was not aware of such adapters. I will look into it. In any case, a permanent setup (without pluggin in and plugging out cables) would be ideal.

Comment: Any Bluetooth transmitter with optical or RCA input should do the trick. @ToniCorinne 's answer is a good example.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the [Avantree Audiokast](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077MXFJGQ) ($50) to connect my bluetooth headphones to my tv, and have been very happy with the functionality. I have mine connected via an optical cable currently.